# The same css gives different styles on localhost and online host

Tags: css, wordpress, fonts, font-family

I am trying to get a font to work properly on my localhost page, but somehow it doesn't.

When I created my page I did it directly online, hosted by infinityfree. I have been doing some stuff there but then I realised I should do that offline, and then upload the changes.

I set up XAMPP and installed wordpress in it.
Then I used a plugin called All-in-one Wordpress Migrator to download a .wpress file of my site, and then I used the same plugin to get my site in the localhost.

I then went into the Custom CSS page and fixed the paths (which aparently may break in localhost) and everything looked fine except the font of the page header title.

This is the original site:
[image: Header of a page from the original site]

This is the localhost site:
[image]

This is the css used to change the font, which is exactly the same on both sites:

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: "BebasNeue";
    src: url(dir/fonts/BebasNeue-Regular.ttf);
}

.page-header-title {
    font-family: BebasNeue;
}

.page-header.background-image-page-header .page-header-title {
    color: #99f;
    font-weight: 900;
}
```

HOWEVER, even though it looks different here, if I go to the main page, it looks perfectly fine in both sites!

Why is this happening?

I can't show you the localhost site for obvious reasons, but the online page is [here](http://kolterdev.epizy.com)

Comment: Check the `src` path in your `@font-face`. You are using a relative path, so make sure the location is the same on your server and that it is finding it.

Comment: I am aware of that, but then it would also break the header from the main page, and that is why I do not understand the problem

Comment: We can only answer based on the CSS you have given us, and there is nothing else there that could cause the problem. It could be to do with some CSS rules taking precedence over others or being overridden elsewhere, but there is really no way we can tell without seeing the relevant CSS.

Comment: The server understands the relative path a bit differently. Try using `src: url(./dir/fonts/BebasNeue-Regular.ttf);`. It needs `.` or `./` to represent the current folder.